# Problemas con XDebug

Tags: php, depuración, xdebug

Estoy probando usar xdebug de php en el Visual Studio Code pero no consigo que funcione. Enumero los pasos que he seguido:

- Uso Ubuntu versión 20.04
- Instalo la extensión Php Debug en el vscode
- Instalo Xdebug `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`
- Configuro mi */etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini* con la siguiente configuración:

[image: xdebug.ini]

Muestro un phpinfo() para ver que se ha instalado bien el xdebug:

[image: phpinfo]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que todo correcto. Le paso la info del phpinfo() a la [pagina de validación del xdebub](https://xdebug.org/wizard)

Obteniendo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por todo ello entiendo que xdebug esta instalado correctamente. Pasamos el vscode

Creo un script muy simple de prueba y creo un launch.json asociado al proyecto con la configuración. Inicio el debug cargo la web en el navegador refresco todo pero no consigo ver nada en la pantalla de depuración de vscode. La siguiente imagen muestra el script el launch y como vemos el vscode no me muestra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado varias configuraciones, cambios de versión de php y no consigo depurar.
En algún paso estoy fallando. Creo que puede ser por la configuración del launch.json aunque no estoy seguro.

¿Alguien me puede dar alguna pista sobre donde tengo el fallo?

En vscode tengo la configuración con php de esta manera por si sirve de algo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITO:**

Si ejecuto el comando `php --ini` obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola. Si tambien lo probe. Lo tengo en el xdebug.ini porque el php si me le esta pillando bien. Si cambio algo en xdebug.ini se refleja en phpinfo(). De todas como te comento los cambios tambien los probe directamente en php.ini y mismo resultado

Comment: Hola. Edito la pregunto para mostrar en una imagen el resultado de `php --ini` He probado meter las configuraciones del xdebug en */etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini* y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Si. En varias lineas y nada. Leyendo documentación creo que el error puede venir por los puertos de escucha. Tengo probar varias cosas a ver .

Answer (score 0):

He dado con el problema. Por lo menos con este cambio ya me funciona. Me faltaba definir en el php.ini el modo de funcionamiento de xdebug. Con la siguiente configuración puesta en el php.ini he conseguido que funcione:

```
[xdebug]
; Path for the library in the extensions folder
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so"
; Values https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#XDEBUG_CONFIG
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

Saludos

Comment: No deberías usar el mismo puerto en `remote_port` y `client_port`